# SQL Exam Normalisation issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database-normalization

Current studying towards a software engineering degree. One of the main topics I study under this umbrella is databases. I just sat my mock exam for this module and I came up across this question about normalising a database to 3NF.

The reason I ask this question is the marking for the mock exam states that the final total number of tables after normalisation is 5. However I got 4 and i'm curious where I went wrong

[Image of the un-normalised data to be normalised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkbKr.png)

The final tables i got are listed as below

Batch_id, Agent_id, Agent_name

batch_id, holiday_code

holiday_code, airport_id, price, quantity

airport_id, airport

Comment: Agent_id, agent_name, otherwise you would repeat agent_name in your first table

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: Please read & act on [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Right now you are just asking us to rewrite your textbook & give a bespoke tutorial & do your homework--that is too broad a question. Give the name & edition of your published academic textbook. Show your work following it. Quote definitions, theorems & algorithms you are using. The first place you are stuck explain about why. (Don't just give some milestones. Without your reasoning we can't tell you where you went wrong or right & we have to redo your reasoning instead of just checking it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I write it down, I come up with the following tables:

```
Agent: agent_id, name
Holiday: holiday_code, price, airport_id
Airport: airport_id, airport_name
Batch: batch_id, agent_id
BatchLine: batch_id, holiday_code, quantity
```

Your answer:

> Batch_id, Agent_id, Agent_name

Agent_id, agent_name, otherwise you would repeat agent_name in your first table – Joakim Danielson

> holiday_code, airport_id, price, quantity

Won't match up for code B563 (different quantities)

Comment: Ahhh, I see where I have went wrong now! Many thanks for your help!

Comment: An airport can have multiple holidays, look at Newcastle, both C930 and A270 are going there (and with different prices). The airport and price are specific to the holiday, and must be in that table.

Comment: indeed i missed that fact.. it might even be debatable if you also need the table `holiday_airport` by the way to remove the `holiday_code` "duplication" in the Holiday table .. But i don't really work following /know the 3NF rules i use [FCO-IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FCO-IM) for "normalization"